# Cowboy webserver crashes on startup after adding ibrowse dependency to Makefile

Tags: makefile, erlang, cowboy

I'm currently developing a server in Erlang using Cowboy as the web server framework.  At startup, I need to be able to make server-side HTTP calls to fetch files from other web servers, so I've included a Makefile dependency to [ibrowse](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse)

The ibrowse documentation does not mention anything specifically about being added as a Cowboy dependency, but the erlang.mk documentation indicates that I only need to add the single line

```
DEPS = ibrowse
```

However, as soon as I add this line, Cowboy crashes on startup with

```
=INFO REPORT==== 15-Feb-2018::14:51:13 ===
    application: geo_server
    exited: {bad_return,
                {{geo_server_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                 {'EXIT',
                     {undef,
                         [{cowboy_router,compile,
                              [[{'_',
                                    [{"/",default_handler,[]},
                                     {"/client_info",client_info_handler,[]},
                                     {"/search",request_handler,[]}]}]],
                              []},
                          {geo_server_app,start,2,
                              [{file,"src/geo_server_app.erl"},{line,8}]},
                          {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                              [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                               {line,273}]}]}}}}
    type: permanent
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,geo_server,{bad_return,{{geo_server_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{cowboy_router,compile,[[{'_',[{\"/\",default_handler,[]},{\"/client_info\",client_info_handler,[]},{\"/search\",request_handler,[]}]}]],[]},{geo_server_app,start,2,[{file,\"src/geo_server_app.erl\"},{line,8}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,\"application_master.erl\"},{line,273}]}]}}}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,geo_server,{bad_return,{{geo_server_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{cowboy_router,compile,[[{'_',[{"/",default_handle
heart: Thu Feb 15 14:51:14 2018: Erlang is crashing .. (waiting for crash dump file)
heart: Thu Feb 15 14:51:14 2018: Would reboot. Terminating.
gmake: *** [erlang.mk:6639: run] Error 1
```

Take this dependency away, and Cowboy starts up fine.

```
PROJECT = geo_server
PROJECT_DESCRIPTION = Geographic information server
PROJECT_VERSION = 0.1.0

DEPS = cowboy
dep_cowboy_commit = 2.2.2
DEP_PLUGINS = cowboy

include erlang.mk

DEPS = ibrowse
```

It also doesn't matter whether I put the `DEPS = ibrowse` before or after the line `include elrang.mk`.

---

After some more noodling around, this seems to a caching problem in the way Cowboy's `make run` process works.

Adding ibrowse seems to require two calls to `make run`.  If my code then crashes, I have to add and then remove ibrowse again before I can see my amended code running.

Thanks

Chris W

Comment: Have you tried in in one line, like DEPS = cowboy ibrowse ?

Comment: @ElvisOric Ah, yes that works.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From erlang.mk [documentation](https://erlang.mk/guide/building.html)

> DEPS List of applications this project depends on that need to be
>   fetched by Erlang.mk.

Solution:
DEPS = cowboy ibrowse

Answer (score 0):

The DEPS need only occur once and contains a space separated list of dependencies